# Jquery ajax success function displaying message

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

On the success function of jquery ajax request i am creating div with a message... But it doesn't seem to show up....

```
success: function(data) {
    $(function() {
        $('<div id="alert">Successfully Updated</div>');

        var $alert = $('#alert');

        if ($alert.length) {
            var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
                $alert.trigger('click');
            }, 3000);

            $alert.animate({ height: $alert.css('line-height') || '50px' }, 200).click(function() {
                window.clearTimeout(alerttimer);
                $alert.animate({ height: '0' }, 200);
            });
        }
    });
```

css:

```
#alert
  {
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: #FF0000;
   height: 0;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font: 20px/40px arial, sans-serif;
   opacity: .9;
  }
```

Comment: what about var alert = $('<div id="alert">Successfully Updated</div>'); and attach it to the dom via append - $("body").append(alert);

Comment: Does the callback contain an "on DOM ready" call for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the newly `created element` to the **DOM tree**.

`jQuery` (better said `Sizzle`) can't query it otherwise. Extend your code like this:

```
 $('<div id="alert">Successfully Updated</div>').appendTo(document.body);
```

Another thing, you should use a `class` instead an `id`. What if there are more than one alerts? You would create multiple divs with identical ids which is a big **nono**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the newly created element to the DOM. Then only it will appear. You can either append the element to body or to a container element.

And also some part of your code is confusing, the timeout function and triggering the click event for the div.

Also `.length` will return a number and not a boolean. And also there is no need for document ready event handler inside the success function.

Comment: on the success function i am creating a div and showing like an message like twitter..

Answer (score 0):

you can either have the div placed within the DOM and use css `display: hidded` and then on a success response you can change `display: block` this way the div will be included in the DOM and you can just toggle kinda.